# Monitor buttons acting totally incorrectly - trying to switch input source instead of showing the OSD

Tags: hdmi, displayport, input, osd

I am a bit new here, English is not my native, so I am sorry for any possible misspelling.

I have a very odd problem - my Xiaomi Mi Surface Display 34" monitor buttons act really strange - instead of calling the monitor OSD, pressing any of 4 present buttons tries to switch to another possible input source (this is even not their function!), but no luck: just 3 seconds of black screen and it turns back to the initial image. Let me explain how I got into this.

I have a monitor named before, which has 4 input ports: 2 DP and 2 HDMI. There is a PC always connected to the monitor via DP interface (DP1 to be exact). Today I tried to connect a second PC via HDMI to the HDMI1 port. It went totally good, I was able to switch between PCs usind a monitor OSD. But I thought it was too long and complicated to press a dozen of buttons on OSD just to change an input source, so started to google any other programmatical methods of doing such thing.

I have found that any VESA-compatible monitor has the 0x60 parameter, which means exactly "input source", so altering the value of this parameter switches the input source without need to call an OSD. I have found that the possible values of this 0x60 parameter for my monitor provided by several utilities are: 0x0F, 0x10, 0x11 and 0x12. But setting any of this values got me no luck - the screen just flashed black and nothing more. Moreover, those utilities showed that the current value of the 0x60 parameter was 0x07 - descripted as "S-Video 1" input source, and it did not change at any made tries. But my monitor does not even have such input ports!

[A utility output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71XDZ.png)

But I discovered a total disaster a bit later - when I tried to switch the input source via OSD, I was not able to call it - any of 4 buttons on the monitor was causing a black flash and nothing more! So OSD is now totally unavailable! This is madness. I can't enter the OSD, I can't change the input source without turning off any one of 2 connected PCs, I can't do anything which is supposed to be made via OSD. Rebooting and reattaching of every possible thing has no effect - even with 2 PCs being connected to monitor and waiting to enter a BIOS password (no OS loaded whatsoever): pressing any button on the monitor causes only black flash and nothing more, no OSD called.

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this, I googled this all day long, but no luck. Please help. Thank you all very much.

Comment: There must be a way to reset the monitor but I cannot find a user manual for it unfortunately.

Comment: @Moab: the factory reset on this monitor is supposed to be done via OSD, which is unavailable... I did a reset by changing the corresponding monitor parameter in the utility - the settings has been definitely set to default, it was noticeable, but the problem still persists

Comment: Post the exact model # of this monitor from the back sticker.

Comment: @LawrenceC I guess I am not able to reproduce all this info by a keyboard, so I made a photo of the back sticker.

https://imgur.com/a/6vgq9y9

Sorry for the late reply, I am in the UTC+3 time zone, it's 8:38 AM here in Russia